# Firebase Standard Events | App Instance Limit

Tags: firebase, parameters, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have 2 problems with Firebase.

1) Can I add custom parameters to standard events in Firebase with GTM?

2) I have read that 500 events can be added per App Instance. Is this just a number that limits the data on the panel? Do I still have 500 event limit problems when I transfer the data to Big Query?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1) The parameters are all strings, you can furthe cast them to timestamps in BigQuery or transform them using any ETL tool.

2) 
- 500 different types of Events per app
- 25 unique parameters with each Event type